# OpenIdDict 3.0 error from ASP.NET Core 3.1 web application

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, openiddict

I am hosting my ASP.NET Core 3 web application in Azure, whenever I do a new publish to Azure, it works as expected. However, the next day, the site is down, then I need to republish again, then it works, then it is down again the following day.

The full error message from Azure is this:

> Application '/LM/W3SVC/975757150/ROOT' with physical root 'D:\home\site\wwwroot' hit unexpected managed exception, exception code = '0xe0434352'. First 30KB characters of captured stdout and stderr logs:
> Unhandled exception.
>
> Internal.Cryptography.CryptoThrowHelper+WindowsCryptographicException: Keyset does not exist
>
> at Internal.NativeCrypto.CapiHelper.CreateProvHandle(CspParameters parameters, Boolean randomKeyContainer)
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeProvHandle()
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider.get_SafeKeyHandle()
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(Int32 keySize, CspParameters parameters, Boolean useDefaultKeySize)
> at System.Security.Cryptography.RSACryptoServiceProvider..ctor(CspParameters parameters)
> at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.<>c.b__66_0(CspParameters csp)
> at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetPrivateKey[T](Func`2 createCsp, Func`2 createCng)
> at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificatePal.GetRSAPrivateKey()
> at Internal.Cryptography.Pal.CertificateExtensionsCommon.GetPrivateKey[T](X509Certificate2 certificate, Predicate`1 matchesConstraints)   at System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.RSACertificateExtensions.GetRSAPrivateKey(X509Certificate2 certificate)   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PrivateKey()   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509SecurityKey.get_PrivateKeyStatus()   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OpenIddictServerBuilder.AddSigningKey(SecurityKey key)   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OpenIddictServerBuilder.AddSigningCertificate(X509Certificate2 certificate)   at ackids.Startup.<ConfigureServices>b__6_6(OpenIddictServerBuilder options) in D:\ackidsRepos\ackids\ackids\Startup.cs:line 154 at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.OpenIddictServerExtensions.AddServer(OpenIddictBuilder builder, Action`1 configuration)
> at ackids.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in D:\ackidsRepos\ackids\ackids\Startup.cs:line 118
> at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor, Boolean wrapExceptions)
> at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.InvokeCore(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass9_0.g__Startup|0(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConfigureServicesBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.b__0(IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.UseStartup(Type startupType, HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.GenericWebHostBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection services)
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
> at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
> at ackids.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\ackidsRepos\ackids\ackids\Program.cs:line 16
> Process Id: 14164.
> File Version: 13.1.21196.18. Description: IIS ASP.NET Core Module V2 Request Handler. Commit: 0a2e366eaf4d29b24b9a98e5782a04bef573189e*

Comment: Are you able to access in local now ? Could you please share your .csproj reference packages ?

Comment: Yes , I can run the web site locally.

Comment: <PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="8.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions" Version="3.1.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.1.12" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.AspNetCore" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="OpenIddict.Server" Version="3.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="SendGrid" Version="9.25.3" />

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error might be the The `OpenIddict` versions that you are using which are not compatible for ASP.NET 3.1.

[image]

[image]
[image]

Try upgrading to the latest versions.

Comment: I have upgraded to the latest version, and wait to see if it resolves the problem, thanks.